# asp.net mvc: directly assign value to model inside razor view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have below snippet inside my Create razor View:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.UnitPrice)
```

trying to directly set `UnitPrice` using statement like this:

```
@Model.UnitPrice = 100;
```

I got something like null pointer exception : `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

How can I assign constant value to a field before posting to create post method?

Comment: instead of setting value in view, set in model: UnitPrice  = 100, but the field should not be const

Comment: The model is a means of conveying information to the view. It is not possible to pass information back to a controller by updating the model in a view. Since you know the value of UnitPrice  why not assign its value where you create the model in the controller?

Comment: @Ian Leaving UnitPrice empty makes controller make validation error since it cannot be null. It seems logical to pass value inside controller but I was looking for a way to assign a value passed from viewbag to UnitPrice field.

Comment: Is the UnitPrice not known when you instantiate the model?

Comment: @Ian it is read from ViewBag.Price value (100 is a sample)

Comment: Initialize anew instance of your model and set the value or `UnitPrice` in the GET method, and pass the model to your view.

Comment: You didn't answer the question. At the point in the code where the model is created do you know the value of UnitPrice ?

Comment: @Ian I know the value in the get method, however i cannot pass it to post method. So i was looking for something like what Stephen recommended.

Comment: So, you weren't creating a model. It would have been clearer had you said this what the problem was.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the value of the property in the model before you pass the model to the view. Assuming your model is

```
public class ProductVM
{
    ....
    public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
}
```

then in the GET method

```
ProductVM model = new ProductVM()
{
    UnitPrice = 100M
};
return View(model);
```

If the value is a 'default' value that applies to all instances, you can also set its value in a parameter-less constructor

```
public class ProductVM
{
    public ProductVM()
    {
        UnitPrice = 100M;
    }
    ....
    public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
}
```

Note that the reason for the `NullReferenceException` is that you have not passed a model to your view.

Answer (score 3):

I think you may be trying to set value after textbox get loaded you need to first pass module from action like

**"return View(objModel);"**

and then you set value

**"@Model.UnitPrice = 100;"**

on top of your view and after write

**"@Html.EditorFor(model => model.UnitPrice)"**

code you will get value into editor.
Thanks..

Comment: based on the original question, this is the only correct answer for the way it is written.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the model's content like this on GET method:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel() 
    {
        UnitPrice = 100M;
    }
    ...
    // if you want constant read-only model in runtime, use readonly keyword before decimal and declare its constructor value
    public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; } 
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult YourView()
{
     ViewModel model = new ViewModel() 
     {
          model.Price = 100M; // if the property is not read-only
     };

     // other logic here

     return View(model);
}

// validation on server-side
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult YourView(ViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // some logic here
    }

    // return type here
}
```