# Pass data via Sessions through different layers (DAL to View)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, session

Goal is to grab the data from database and show the customer's name when logged in as **Welcome, (Name here)**.  All i get is a null reference so i'm not passing it right.

I call it from this method to grab the name of customer in namespace for DAL:

```
public bool insertCusReg(CustomerCTX inCusReg)
    {
        var db = new BankContext();
        try
        {
                var newCus = new Customer();

                string salt = addSalt();
                var passwordAndSalt = inCusReg.Password + salt;
                byte[] passwordDB = makeHash(passwordAndSalt);
                newCus.Firstname = inCusReg.Firstname;
                newCus.Lastname = inCusReg.Lastname;
                newCus.SSN = inCusReg.SSN;
                newCus.Password = passwordDB;
                newCus.ConfirmPassword = inCusReg.ConfirmPassword;
                newCus.Salt = salt;

                db.Customer.Add(newCus);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return true;

        }

        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Call this method from Controller:

```
  public ActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(CustomerCTX inCusReg)
    {

        var bankDb = new DBBankBLL();  // getting called from another method which is mentioned below       
        bool insertOK = bankDb.user_in_db(inCusReg);   

        if (insertOK)
        {

            Session["codeValid"] = true;
            Session["name"] = inCusReg.Firstname;
            return RedirectToAction("MyProfile", "Home");
        }
        else
        {
            Session["LoggedIn"] = false;
            ViewBag.LoggedIn = false;
            return View();
        }
    }
```

This is the BLL part which is getting called from above:

```
 public bool user_in_db(CustomerCTX inCusReg)
    {
        var DBBankDAL = new DBBankDAL();
        return DBBankDAL.user_in_db(inCusReg);
    }
```

And finally output the customers name in this View:

```
@if (Session["codeValid"] != null && Session["name"] != null )
{

ViewBag.Message = "Welcome, " + Session["name"].ToString(); ;

<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
            @ViewBag.Message
            @*@User.Identity.Name*@
            <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="@Url.Action("RegPay", "Home")"> Register Payement</a></li>
            <li><a href="@Url.Action("OverviewRegPay", "Home")"> Overview of Payement</a></li>
            <li><a href="@Url.Action("ListOfConfirmedRegPay", "Home")"> List of Confirmed Payement</a></li>
            <li><a href="@Url.Action("MyProfile", "Home")"> My Profile</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="@Url.Action("Logout", "Home")"> Log out  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
}
```

Model is:

```
public class CustomerCTX
{
    //[Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "First Name:")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage ="Firstname is required.")]
    public string Firstname { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Last Name:")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Lastname is required.")]
    public string Lastname { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Social Security Number:")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Social Security Number is required.")]
    [RegularExpression(@"[0-9]{11}$", ErrorMessage = "SSN can only conatin numbers and must be 11 digits long.")]
    public Int64 SSN { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Password:")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is required.")]
    [RegularExpression(@"[A-Z, a-z, 0-9]{6,}$", ErrorMessage = "Password must conatin minimum 6 characters")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Confirm Password:")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "Please confirm your password")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

}
```

Still a freshman to programming and still learning.
Hopefully someone can spot where I went wrong and much appreciate for all the help!

Comment: Can you show your model?

Comment: coming right up

Comment: So in your controller assign the values to your model properties and use those in the view.

Comment: How should i do that?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37531271/asp-net-mvc-directly-assign-value-to-model-inside-razor-view

Comment: I see now, I have edited the post, but I do not want hardcode the values manually. I want the database to fetch the customer's name that are logged in.

Comment: You can do that as well, but I suggest doing some more research first.

Comment: been doing research for several days before i asked for tips here xD but if you do have other resources i can look at, pls share ^^

Comment: You might want to try the MVC tutorial shown here (put you on the database access part): https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-4